# CasperJS trouble with click() not finding element

Tags: casperjs

Just getting into CasperJS, and I came across a weird behaviour. This is part of my script. It looks for a link that looks like this:

```
<a id="logout" href="...">xxx</a>
```

I have a unique tag on it to help locate it. The test.assertExists() works, but the this.click() does not. This is puzzling, as they have the same selector.

```
casper.test.begin('Initial login & logout testing', 2, function suite(test) {
    casper.start(startUrl);

    casper.then(function() {
    this.waitForSelector('li a#logout', function() {
        test.assertExists('a#logout', "logout button is found");
        this.click('a#logout');
        });
    });
    casper.run(function() {
        test.done();
    });
});
```

Output:

```
PASS logout button is found
[debug] [phantom] Mouse event 'mousedown' on selector: a#logout
[error] [remote] mouseEvent(): Couldn't find any element matching 'a#logout' selector
```

I expected consistent behavior. Any clues?
Thanks!

[UPDATE] I have a workaround. I replace this.click('a#logout'); with the following:

```
        this.evaluate(function() {
            document.querySelector('a#logout').click();
        });
```

It does the trick. I use this for now, although I wish I knew why it did not work the way expected.

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem... Is it possible for that `<a>` tag changed for some reason(JavaScript remove that `<a>` tag or change its id)?

Comment: Can you try removing `casper.then` and just using

`casper.waitForSelector('li a#logout', function ...`  or trying `casper.click('li a#logout')`

Comment: I tried and no luck so far.

Comment: Probably you have multiple elements matching the same selector. Try to narrow it down to select only one. That could help.

Comment: I have experienced the exact same thing. I wait for the selector using casper.waitForSelector(), I test to check it exists using casper.exists() and then click it using casper.click(). At the click CasperJS suddenly reports "Couldn't find any element matching selector".